# Does match.arg provide enough protection against SQL injection?

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

I wish to insert data into my postgres table with the `RPostgreSQL` package, except I wish to dynamically choose the field name. For example:

```
library(RPostgreSQL)
insert_data <- function(conn_obj, num_to_insert, field_name = c('col1', 'col2')){

       field_name <- match.arg(field_name)
       query <- paste0('insert into table1 (', 
                       field_name, 
                       ') VALUES $1')

       postgresqlExecStatement(conn_obj,
                               query,
                               list(num_to_insert))


}
```

`insert_data` works by dynamically building the query containing the field name where `num_to_insert` should be put. I am worried about the possibility of sql injection, so my question is, does `match.arg` protect me against sql injection? Are there any other ways of building such a query such that the field name can be used as a (sanitised) variable?